# How to prevent an element in react (nextjs) to load if it hidden in tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css, next.js13, react-server-components

In my next.js application, I'm using Tailwind CSS classes to control the visibility of elements. However, I want to ensure that elements are not loaded at all if they are hidden using Tailwind classes. How can I achieve this behavior to optimize the loading of my components?

classes:
`hidden`

this is the rendered code for the component

```
<div class="gap-4 md:gap-8 fcc">
   <div class="icon">
      <div class="relative w-[40px] h-[40px] pointer hover:border border-gray-600 rounded md:block hidden">
         <button type="button" >
              //This element data should be rendered when it is set to visible only
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="relative w-8 h-8 overflow-hidden rounded-full bg-slate-600 ">
        \\ user botton code here
   </div>
   <div class="w-fit md:hidden fc">
      <button type="button" aria-haspopup="dialog" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="radix-:R1tlla:" data-state="closed">
         //This element data should be rendered when it is set to visible only
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

FYI using server components
thanks in advance if anyone help me solve this

Comment: I think this is premature optimization. But if you really want to not load the element, using CSS classes (or Tailwind) is definitely not the way to go. You should try using some logics like js or tertiary operator.

Comment: ty, @ngtrthinh for the read, agree with u but trying to optimize AMAP because it affects 50% of file size here, it may seem premature but it is a real issue, give this a read it may help you, [link](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14810?sort=new)  for this "tertiary operator" it is not that simple without getting client screen width because what will you compare things from, right so, my approach for this issue is first load parent element on the screen that will have client dimentions and then it will pass it to the child componets which will render on server with specifics.